# How to refer/Handel a dynamic button in selenium ide

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

I am trying to record a script in selenium IDE where when *back* **button is clicked**, the previous page should get loaded/opened. when i replay the script IDE shows an  error as "**element not found**" and the script fails

i have tried all the possible options for **Locators** but the application which i am testing **randomly changes** the *id* of the button every time when the page is refreshed

please help me ASAP.
Thanks already!!!

Comment: If you could add some HTML, the line containing the element you want to click, and a few lines above it, we should be able to help you with a locator.

Comment: i am stuck here!! please somebody help!!! even **Webdriver** refuses to identify the button! attaching the inspect element HTML of the object `<button id="button-1141-btnEl" class="x-btn-center" autocomplete="off" role="button" hidefocus="true" type="button" data-qtip="Add Claim" style="height: 14px;">
</em>`

Comment: Without more HTML lines above the button you want to find (at least 3-5 lines, preferably more than that) it will be difficult to build a selector that will find the exact element you want.  Barring that, I'd recommend looking for a unique ID, Class, or Name above the element you want, then constructing a selector similar to `"div.divClass>table>tr>td>[id$='btnEl']"`.  You can edit your original question and add the HTML to it.

Answer (score 4):

I'd examine the ID, and figure out which part does not change.

If the section of the ID that does not change is in the middle, then use this:

```
css=[id*='idPart']
```

If the section of the ID that does not change is at the end:

```
css=[id$='idSuffix']
```

If the section of the ID that does not change is at the beginning:

```
css=[id^='idPrefix']
```

Comment: Are you intending to say Inspecting the element in firebug?   If so, I have Inspected the BUTTON and this is what i get as the attributes of that button...<em id="button-1104-btnWrap">
<button id="button-1104-btnEl" class="x-btn-center" autocomplete="off" role="button" hidefocus="true" type="button" data-qtip="Back" style="height: 16px;">
</em>

Comment: And when i inspect the button after refreshing the page ... i get ... <em id="button-1232-btnWrap">
<button id="button-1232-btnEl" class="x-btn-center" autocomplete="off" role="button" hidefocus="true" type="button" data-qtip="Back" style="height: 16px;">
</em>..............As you can clearly see that the **ID** has **Changed** after refresh...

Comment: Yes, but you could use `css=[id$='-btnEl']`, assuming no other control in your page has "-btnEl" at the end.

Comment: There are multiple buttons in the page i am testing with id's starting from **button**, ending by **btnEl** and the only difference between them is the middle part (number) which changes at every refresh!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
command: click

target: //button[@type='button']
```

If the button has any specific "value" then you can put this in the `value` field, if not then just try those two lines of code above.

Answer (score -1):

You can use html address. In my case I have used as below.

"html/body/div[3]/div[2]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[2]/div/input"

So I implemented in TARGET field as below.

xpath=html/body/div[3]/div[2]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[2]/div/input

Note: Actually it is not correct practice but no any solution if multiple buttons are present on the page

Regards,
Sachin Deshpande